# Oracle Form Builder, View Data From Database Table

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have an Oracle form builder project, I want a button when clicking on it then it gets the data from Student table in the database and fill it in the table of the tabular canvas.

What is the code or the function required?

Answer (score 0):

Typically one would create a data block in the form with the student table as the base table, which would cause the data block to fill when execute-query is performed.

Answer (score -2):

1- use when-button-pressed trigger and write the code 
go_block('your data block name ');
execut